# Visual Studio Code (ctrl+E in Brackets) where is this shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been looking for a function in VSC that in Brackets is in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. When you edit class in html file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> the window with CSS editor with this class opens, how can I have it in VSC?

Comment: Have you tried F12?

Comment: Yes but I am getting "no definition found" :(

Comment: ok now i know install css peek and then <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>12</kbd> and its working, You can quick edit html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**CSS Peek Extention**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) for VS CODE.

Steps to setup:

1. Install CSS Peek extension either from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) or using vscode:

[image]

2. To use it: Press <kbd>F12</kbd> while the *element/class/id* is selected or has a cursor in it and it will open the window, like this:

[image]

---

If you want to change the keyboard shortcut to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> then follow the below image (bottom to top) and double click on the green one and then just press the shortcut you want like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>:

[image]